# how to enable api flags in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubernetes-apiserver

The below screenshot shows the kubernetes document to enable API server flags, but no clear instructions were given on where to change these API server flags. I'm using kubernetes on digital ocean cloud. I can not use hpa. [image]
kubernetes version is:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how your api-server is running. If it's as a service on the master node, @kishorebjv may have your answer, but if the api-server runs as a pod in kubernetes you should only have to add the flags to the `args` for that deployment/daemonset.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a apiserver.conf file in master node & mount it in /etc/kubernetes/ directory of apiserver container. This will help you to customize your API server.
here is the [sample code](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/control-plane-flags/#apiserver-flags) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get working HPA in your kubernetes cluster. I have written a step by step answer for that, how can you achieve it:

[How to Enable KubeAPI server for HPA Autoscaling Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725248/how-to-enable-kubeapi-server-for-hpa-autoscaling-metrics/53727101#53727101)

Please have a look. Hope this helps

Comment: i followed your answer and I installed metrics server. after I created my hpa the TARGETS stuck in <unknown>/50%. What am I missing? @prafull

Comment: Result for kubectl get events:
Warning   FailedGetResourceMetric        HorizontalPodAutoscaler   unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
Warning   FailedComputeMetricsReplicas   HorizontalPodAutoscaler   failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)

Comment: Did you `kubectl apply -f` all the files in `metrics-server/deploy/1.8+` folder. If yes this should have worked.

Comment: i did everything exactly as you mentioned, but not working.
metric server pod status is "CrashLoopsBackOff" @prafull

Comment: I have updated my original answer, Kindly try that and let me know if you face any issue?

Comment: hey @prafull I added authentication-token-webhook: true
horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients: true in `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` still i'm unable to get it work. Here is what im getting for `kubectl get apiservices`
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   False (MissingEndpoints)

Comment: Did you followed replaced the `metrics-server-deployment` file from the yaml file I have provided in the answer? If yes `metrics-server` pod is in running state?

Comment: `horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients: true` should not be there, that flag is not of kubelet. Please remove that flag from kubelet conf and restart the kubelet

Comment: yes i followed `metrics-server-deployment` given by you.
`metrics-server` is not in running state, it's in CrashLoopBackOff state @prafull

Comment: I have removed that flag `horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients: true` and restarted the kubelet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185141/discussion-between-prafull-ladha-and-aathith-rajendran).

Comment: one more doubt @prafull!! `systemctl status kubelet` showing `Dec 12 12:31:01 kube-master kubelet[8529]: E1212 12:31:01.885511    8529 azure_dd.go:147] failed to get azure cloud in GetVolumeLimits, plugin.host: kube-master`. I'm not using azure, I'm using Digital ocean cloud. why this error is showing?

Comment: I am not familiar with digitial ocean kubernetes cluster. I am not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0):

The `kube-apiserver` usually runs as a static pod. This means it is managed directly by the `kubelet` on a specific node, without the API server observing it and therefore it cannot be updated using `kubectl` commands.

Most of the times you can find the `kube-apiserver` pod running in the `kube-system` namespace.

```bash
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

The `kubelet` loads its config and then starts watching the static pods manifests directory. The path where you are most likely to find the `kube-apiserver.yaml` definition is `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` on the K8s node. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9b5e2dc54d2315402a462e75c168bfc4ce28ecf3/cmd/kubeadm/app/constants/constants_test.go#L27C1-L27C1) is a unit test for this action in the K8s source code.

Updating `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` will automatically redeploy the pod with the new config, including the flags you need.