# Kubernetes Rolling Update not obeying 'maxUnavailable' replicas when redeployed in autoscaled conditions

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, autoscaling

In a nutshell, most of our apps are configured with the following `strategy` in the Deployment -

```
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
```

The Horizonatal Pod Autoscaler is configured as so

```
spec:
  maxReplicas: 10
  minReplicas: 2
```

Now when our application was redeployed, instead of running a rolling update, it instantly terminated 8 of our pods and dropped the number of pods to `2` which is the min number of replicas available. This happened in a fraction of a second as you can see here.

[image]

Here is the output of `kubectl get hpa` -

[image]

As `maxUnavailable` is 25%, shouldn't only about 2-3 pods go down at max ? Why did so many pods crash at once ? It seems as though rolling update is useless if it works this way.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Could you please share the output of "kubectl describe hpa"

Comment: @Nepomucen have updated

Comment: Have added an issue on the k8 github - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/72231

Comment: Based on the above Github issue and the response it appears the answer by @Almenon below is the right one?

Answer (score 2):

After looking at this question, I decided to try this with test Environment where I wanted to check If it doesn't work.

I have setup the `metrics-server` to fetch the metrics server and set a HPA. I have followed the following steps to setup the HPA and deployment:

[How to Enable KubeAPI server for HPA Autoscaling Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725248/how-to-enable-kubeapi-server-for-hpa-autoscaling-metrics/53727101#53727101)

Once, I have working HPA and max `10 pods` running on system, I have updated the images using:

```
[root@ip-10-0-1-176 ~]# kubectl get hpa
NAME         REFERENCE               TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
php-apache   Deployment/php-apache   49%/50%   1         10        10         87m

[root@ip-10-0-1-176 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
load-generator-557649ddcd-6jlnl   1/1     Running   0          61m
php-apache-75bf8f859d-22xvv       1/1     Running   0          91s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-dv5xg       1/1     Running   0          106s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-g4zgb       1/1     Running   0          106s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-hv2xk       1/1     Running   0          2m16s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-jkctt       1/1     Running   0          2m46s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-nlrzs       1/1     Running   0          2m46s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-ptg5k       1/1     Running   0          106s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-sbctw       1/1     Running   0          91s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-tkjhb       1/1     Running   0          55m
php-apache-75bf8f859d-wv5nc       1/1     Running   0          106s
[root@ip-10-0-1-176 ~]# kubectl set image deployment php-apache php-apache=hpa-example:v1 --record
deployment.extensions/php-apache image updated

[root@ip-10-0-1-176 ~]# kubectl get pods
NAME                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
load-generator-557649ddcd-6jlnl   1/1     Running             0          62m
php-apache-75bf8f859d-dv5xg       1/1     Terminating         0          2m40s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-g4zgb       1/1     Terminating         0          2m40s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-hv2xk       1/1     Terminating         0          3m10s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-jkctt       1/1     Running             0          3m40s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-nlrzs       1/1     Running             0          3m40s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-ptg5k       1/1     Terminating         0          2m40s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-sbctw       0/1     Terminating         0          2m25s
php-apache-75bf8f859d-tkjhb       1/1     Running             0          56m
php-apache-75bf8f859d-wv5nc       1/1     Terminating         0          2m40s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-7cbds       1/1     Running             0          6s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-7vh69       1/1     Running             0          6s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-9hdz4       1/1     Running             0          6s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-dlltb       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          3s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-nwcn6       1/1     Running             0          6s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-p8c54       1/1     Running             0          6s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-pg8h8       0/1     Pending             0          3s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-pqzjw       0/1     Pending             0          2s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-q8j4d       0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4s
php-apache-847c8ff9f4-xpbzl       0/1     Pending             0          1s
```

Also, I have kept job in background which pushed the `kubectl get pods` output every second in a file. At no time till all images are upgraded, number of pods never went below 8.

I believe you need to check how you're setting up your rolling upgrade. Are you using deployment or replicaset? I have kept the `rolling update` strategy same as you `maxUnavailable: 25%` and `maxSurge: 25%` with deployment and it is working well for me.

Answer (score 2):

In our case we added the `replicas` field a while ago and forgot to remove it when we added the HPA. The HPA does not play nice with the `replicas` field during deployments, so if you have a HPA remove the `replicas` field. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#migrating-deployments-and-statefulsets-to-horizontal-autoscaling

> When an HPA is enabled, it is recommended that the value of spec.replicas of the Deployment and / or StatefulSet be removed from their manifest(s). If this isn't done, any time a change to that object is applied, for example via kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml, this will instruct Kubernetes to scale the current number of Pods to the value of the spec.replicas key. This may not be desired and could be troublesome when an HPA is active.

> Keep in mind that the removal of spec.replicas may incur a one-time degradation of Pod counts as the default value of this key is 1 (reference Deployment Replicas). Upon the update, all Pods except 1 will begin their termination procedures. Any deployment application afterwards will behave as normal and respect a rolling update configuration as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out the `minReadySeconds`  property.

The `minReadySeconds`  property that specifies  how  long  a  newly  created  pod  should  be ready before the pod is treated as available. Actually the redeploying that without `minReadySeconds`'s property has been done successfully in a very short time. But after short time **readiness probe** started to failing for any reason and the pods  start scale down.

`maxUnavailable` property is only taken care about while RollingUpdate. After RollingUpdate event this property ignored.

Note from [Kubernetes In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action)'s book : If  you  only  define  the  readiness  probe  without  setting  **minReadySeconds** properly, new pods are considered available immediately when the first invocation  of  the  readiness  probe  succeeds.  If  the  readiness  probe  starts  failing shortly  after,  the  bad  version  is  rolled  out  across  all  pods.  Therefore,  you should set **minReadySeconds** appropriately.