# Kubernetes in Azure cannot display CPU usage for HPA then cannot perform auto-scaling

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage, missing-data, autoscaling, azure-aks

I tried [solutions from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725248/how-to-enable-kubeapi-server-for-hpa-autoscaling-metrics/53727101#53727101) but failed to get CPU usage (it still show <unknown>).

Below are steps that I performed:

> 1. Clone the metrics-server github repo: git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server.git
> 2. Add below lines under "imagePullPolicy" in metrics-server-deployment.yaml:

```
  command:
  - /metrics-server
  - --metric-resolution=30s
  - --kubelet-insecure-tls
  - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

> 3. Go into directory cd deploy/1.8+ and run following yaml files:
>
>    - kubectl apply -f aggregated-metrics-reader.yaml
>    - kubectl apply -f auth-reader.yaml
>    - kubectl apply -f auth-delegator.yaml
>    - kubectl apply -f metrics-apiservice.yaml
>    - kubectl apply -f resource-reader.yaml
>    - kubectl apply -f metrics-server-deployment.yaml
>    - kubectl apply -f metrics-server-service.yaml
>
> 4.a) Run sample pod:

`kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 php-apache --image=k8s.gcr.io/hpa-example --requests=cpu=200m --expose --port=80`

> 5. Faced error when create HPA:
>
>    kubectl autoscale deployment php-apache --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10 horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/php-apache autoscaled
>
>    **error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'kubectl get resource/' instead of 'kubectl get resource resource/'**
>
> 4.b) Run my pod and recreate HPA
>
> --> still display  in CPU usage when "kubectl get hpa"

How can I set to retrieve CPU usage properly?

Provide more information for HPA below:

[image: Output of HPA]

[image: Describe of HPA]

Comment: Could you please add output of `kubectl get hpa` and `kubectl decribe hpa <hpa_name>`

Comment: Added outputs already, please help to have a look, thanks

Comment: I changed 4.a) to "kubectl run php-apache --image=k8s.gcr.io/hpa-example --requests=cpu=200m --expose --port=80" then have Deployment in Kubernetes, but still cannot get CPU usage.

Comment: Your HPA is still using heapster, rather than metrics server to get the CPU metrics and hence the issue.

Comment: How can I set to use metrics-server ?

Comment: For metrics-server to work you need kubernetes 1.8+ version, could you check the kuberenetes version you're on. Also check if metrics-server pod is up and running in kube-system namespace?

Comment: Kubernetes's Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2"...,  Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.11"...  . What are commands to start metrics-server? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187549/discussion-between-prafull-ladha-and-daikeung).